# An if loop omitting an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings like this`var arr = ['BUTTON','BADGE','CHECKBOX]'`
Now I need a `if` condition to be written for the strings except those present in the array. How do I do that??
I'm a beginner and know nothing much about javascript. Thanks in advance for your help.
I tried `var arr = ['BUTTON','BADGE','CHECKBOX];
if(!arr){
//code to be executed
}` 
However this always returns false.

Comment: You want to test if a string is present in the array or not ?

Comment: use ES6 `includes()`

Comment: `if(!arr){`  that just means if the array does not exist.  But of course the array exist's, you defined it the line above, as is why your always get false.

Comment: @Keith Thank you very much sir just found out my mistake.

Comment: @KrisnaPrashatt in my answer i showed you how to do it

Comment: Set's are good..  `var notThese = new Set(['BUTTON','BADGE','CHECKBOX']); notThese.has("BUTTON"); //true`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
if(arr.indexOf(test_variable) === -1){
  // element doesn't exist in array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question but maybe array.some can solve your problem:

```js
var someString = 'BADGE';
var arr = ['BUTTON','BADGE','CHECKBOX' ];

if (arr.some(str => str === someString)) {
    console.log("Exist");
} else {
    console.log("Doesn't exist");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it:

```js
var pippo = "pippo";

var arr = ['BUTTON','BADGE','CHECKBOX'];

if(arr.indexOf(pippo) > -1){ 
  console.log("contained!");
}
else{
  console.log("not contained!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the last element of your array/list is not properly written as a string i.e **'CHECKBOX**. You missed a single quote in the end so it should be **'CHECKBOX'**

```
var arr = ['BUTTON','BADGE','CHECKBOX];
```

↓

```
var arr = ['BUTTON','BADGE','CHECKBOX'];
```

Secondly coming to your actual query, according to your question it seems you want to run a piece of code if a string is not present in the array.
For this, you can use the **array.indexOf()** function which returns the position/index of the variable in the array passed as a parameter to it & if the variable is not present in the array, it returns a value of **-1**

More about this:- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

So the code for that would be:-

```
var arr = ['BUTTON','BADGE','CHECKBOX'];
var str = 'foo';    //string not present in the array i.e arr
if(arr.indexOf(str) === -1) {
     //your code here
}
```

Answer (score -3):

length will works for you if comes 0, return 0 when not element exists in the arrayset

```
var arr = ['BUTTON','BADGE','CHECKBOX'];

console.log(arr.length)
```